# How to validate parameters for rest controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, parameters

I have multiple parameters that are not required. I was wondering if it is possible to validate non-required parameters. For instance, I have "name" field which is not a required parameter. I want to check if it is not blank when api is exposed.

```
@GetMapping
public Response method(@RequestParam("firstname") @NotBlank String firstName) {
...
...
```

I am new to spring and rest controller so I am not sure if this is even right approach. I want this api to not require firstname but if it is in parameter, I want to make sure something is in there. Is this possible to achieve? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Size(min = 1)` instead of `@NotBlank` then null elements are considered valid.

```
@GetMapping
public Response method(@RequestParam("firstname") @Size(min = 1) String firstName) {
```

And make sure you are using proper [configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable#configuration) to validate request param